# Parse json with same key but different values

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pyspark

Hello I have json which looks like this:

```
json={'Cells': [{'Value': 'Total Assets'},
                {'Value': '24203.13'},
                {'Value': '5438.48'}]}
```

While parsing this json to dataframe I get next column

```
   | Value  |
   ----------
   Total Assets
   24203.13
   5438.48
```

But I want to get table in next way:

```
  | Total Assets | 24203.13 | 5438.48 |
```

How to create such table from my json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a working solution for you ..

As you have already parsed the json file, taking it from there, create a dummy column in order to group by and use **`collect_list()`** to club all the elements in one single column. Then take out every element of your choice

## Create the dataframe here

```
json={'Cells': [{'Value': 'Total Assets'},
                {'Value': '24203.13'},
                {'Value': '5438.48'}]}
df = spark.createDataFrame([(json)])
df.show(truncate=False)
df = df.withColumn("array_col", F.explode("Cells"))
df = df.withColumn("Value", df.array_col.getItem("Value"))
df.show(truncate=False)
df_grp = df.withColumn("dummy_col", F.lit(1))
df_grp = df_grp.groupBy("dummy_col").agg(F.collect_list("Value").alias("Value"))
df_grp.select("dummy_col", df_grp.Value[0],df_grp.Value[1],df_grp.Value[2]).show()
```

## Input

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Cells                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[Value -> Total Assets], [Value -> 24203.13], [Value -> 5438.48]]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## Intermediate Output after JSON Parsing

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|Cells                                                             |array_col              |Value       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|[[Value -> Total Assets], [Value -> 24203.13], [Value -> 5438.48]]|[Value -> Total Assets]|Total Assets|
|[[Value -> Total Assets], [Value -> 24203.13], [Value -> 5438.48]]|[Value -> 24203.13]    |24203.13    |
|[[Value -> Total Assets], [Value -> 24203.13], [Value -> 5438.48]]|[Value -> 5438.48]     |5438.48     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+
```

## Final Output

```
+---------+------------+--------+--------+
|dummy_col|    Value[0]|Value[1]|Value[2]|
+---------+------------+--------+--------+
|        1|Total Assets|24203.13| 5438.48|
+---------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Sorry for such questions but can we contact somehow ? Because I have big json and can't paste it here. Json in my question was just part of that big json.I tried to re write your code to parse my big json but couldn't do it

Comment: We can connect in Linkedin .. Can you please help accept and upvote the answer .. Will really appreciate that

Comment: Yes of course I accepted it as answer.What is your profile in LinkedIn?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/dipanjan-saha-5874b1a0/